# Is there a cross-browser and cross-frame way to check if an object is an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cross-browser

Given an object `obj`, I would like to check if that object is a native HTML element. I could do:

```
if ( obj instanceof HTMLElement )
```

but that doesn't work across frames (e.g. on objects from an `<iframe>`) since each frame has its own `HTMLElement` constructor. Alternatively, I could just do:

```
if ( obj.tagName )
```

but that's not safe/reliable, as such a property could be (un)intentionally added to the object.

So, is there a reliable way to do this?

Comment: element.outerHTML.match(/^<html/i)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following, accepting the fact that this will only work for UAs that support `HTMLElement` as a base contructor:

```
/// testing vars
var localBody = document.body;
var foreignBody = document.getElementById('iframe').contentDocument.body;

/// useful function
var deriveWindow = function( elm ){
    return elm && 
        elm.ownerDocument && 
        (elm.ownerDocument.defaultView || 
        elm.ownerDocument.parentWindow)
    ;
};

/// instanceofs
console.log( localBody instanceof HTMLElement );
console.log( foreignBody instanceof HTMLElement );
console.log( localBody instanceof deriveWindow(localBody).HTMLElement );
console.log( foreignBody instanceof deriveWindow(foreignBody).HTMLElement );
```

The output will vary from browser to browser, Firefox 25 (on Windows 7) gives:

```
true
true
true
true
```

Whereas IE 11, Opera 12, Safari 5 and Chrome 31 (on Windows 7) all give:

```
true
false
true
true
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/9sGx5/7/
- http://jsfiddle.net/9sGx5/7/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

Best way I know how is to check the toString representation of the object.

Two things will always be true of an HTMLElement's string representation:

1. It will start with `[object HTML`
2. It will end with `Element]`

Here's the verbose way to check:

```
var str = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj),
    isHtmlElement = str.indexOf('[object HTML') === 0 
                 && str.indexOf('Element]') > -1;
```

There is still some (but minimal) potential for a false positive.

Comment: ES6: `var isHTMLElement = object => {
  var string = {}.toString.call(object);
  return string.startsWith('[object HTML') && string.endsWith('Element]');
};`

Comment: See https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/427#issuecomment-30357634: Host object `[[Class]]` names are implementation-dependent — `({}).toString.call(document.documentElement) == '[object Object]'` in IE 6 and 7, and the `HTML*Element` interfaces are not exposed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nodeType and nodeName properties, unfortunately you still run into problems if these properties get added to a non-HTML element object.

http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodetype.asp

```
//Returns true if it is a DOM element    
function isElement(o){
    if (typeof o === "object" && o.nodeType === 1 && typeof o.nodeName==="string") {
        return true;
    } 
    return false;    
 }
```

Comment: This is also the method that underscore.js uses.  `_.isElement = function(obj) { return !!(obj && obj.nodeType === 1); };`

Answer (score 0):

How about the `isPrototypeOf` function?   `HTMLElement.prototype.isPrototypeOf(obj)` should return `true` for any HTML element, but `false` for some random object.

I haven't had the chance to test it out across frames, so my one concern would be if it runs into the same issue that `instanceOf` does . . .